# Httpwebrequst returns 500 internal server error while sending jsonconvert.serializeobject

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

We are sending `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstobject);` to the URL here. `lstobject` is a large list sent to the `url.error` also returned after 3 minutes to log error how to make webrequest to wait 5 minutes.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest        
    .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonPayloadPostUrl"]
    .ToString());
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000000;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(jsonPayload);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

}
```

Ee have used  `httpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000000;` but the server is unable to send request back in less than 5 minutes. How to make request to wait  for server for response ?

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something reading your question, but HTTP 500 server error means that the server has provided a response, saying it encountered some internal issue. So you cannot prevent it by setting a bigger timeout on the Request side.

Following https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

> Internal Error 500
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request.

I would say either your request is not properly built, or the server has some application-side issue.

Coming back to the timeout setting way, I think it looks properly. Please note that this time might be taking into account topics like DNS name resolution etc. which in turn might require a bit more time than it seems in the first place. This shouldn't be a problem in your case though, looking at the value you are trying to set.

Comment: you are having internal sever issue that's why getting 500 error

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.what u have said is correct one when list size is not too huge server giving proper response this was a case with very huge list and the way we are preparing value is correct why becoz for small list its giving response but for large list its giving internal server error thats why i am concetrating on httpwebrequest timeout.